# Problem after "sudo apt-get install fglrx-amdcccle"

Tags: drivers

After I enter `sudo apt-get install fglrx-amdcccle` my Ubuntu 15.04 not enter to desktop and just ask password. When I enter password again ask also change resolution (show big).

What can I do to fix the problem?

Comment: Did you try reinstalling the driver?

Comment: How i can reinstall the driver?

Comment: Recovery mode and `sudo apt-get purge` the package, then `sudo apt-get install` again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your login screen, press `ctrl+alt+f1` you should be in tty now, login using your username and password. Now

Issue the commands one by one. Make sure you have a working Internet connection.

```
sudo apt-get purge "fglrx.*"
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
sudo reboot
```